# Automate Page Unprotect Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, datetime

I need to find a way to automate the password 'unprotect' feature of Wordpress. We do our weekly product drop over the weekend when there's no one in the office, and it often doesn't get released to our customers on time. Here's what I see when I inspect the 'unprotect' link.

```
<a style="cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;" data-ppw-status="1" onclick="ppwpRowAction.handleOnClickRowAction(10)" id="ppw-protect-post_10" class="ppw-protect-action" title="Protect this page">Protect</a>
```

I'm thinking I will need a script to automate the 5 links at a given day and time (Saturday at 12 noon ET).

Answer (score 0):

All posts in WordPress, including pages and WooCommerce products, have a publication date and time. You can set that date / time to sometime in the future. If you do that, they won't be visible to your audience until that time arrives.

You can use the Bulk Edit feature in the All Posts or All Products dashboard panel to quickly set it for multiple items.

If you do your product drop at noon on Saturdays, just put that into the publication date / time.

Comment: The problem I see is that we have some high level customers who are granted early access.

Comment: Ah, that changes your question completely. Maybe ask another question?

Comment: I'm not sure how it changes the question. We grant early access by giving those specific customers the password for the protected pages. I need a way to unprotect the pages at a certain time so all our customers can have access.